# mapboxer r add_draw_control() not working in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, mapbox

I am having problems adding `add_draw_control()` to Mapbox map using mapboxer. It works using the suggested examples e.g.

```
    mapboxer(
      center = c(9.5, 40.5),
      zoom = 7
    ) %>%
      add_draw_control(
        displayControlsDefault = FALSE,
        controls = list(
          polygon = TRUE,
          trash = TRUE
        )
      )
```

but the same doesn't work when put into a Shiny app. I would like a user to be able to draw a polygon on a map and get the information from `...on_click` for further analysis. Any help much appreciated.